# Ecommerce site that displays product list in Bengali and Hindi language as well

Tags: e-commerce

Is there any ecommerce extension under Joomla that has the feature to display product list in Bengali and Hindi language together with English? Suppose my product list has pen, pencil, eraser as objects. What I need is users with an option to view product list in English or Hindi or Bengali. I need human-translated product list (unlike [Gtranslate](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/gtranslate) which is already installed).

Answer (score 2):

Joomla displays one language at a time, but allows for language switching.

The leading extension for Joomla that does ecommerce is Virtuemart - although it has a long history, intersparced with vulnerable versions, it is the most mature of the extensions in this category.

-- http://www.virtuemart.net/

It can be set up with a multilingual store.

First make sure Joomla 3.4.5+ [multi-language setup is correct](http://help.joomla.org/files/EN-GB_multilang_tutorial.pdf)

There is also a [nice Multilingual Webinar on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnhVVtyejPg)

Comment: @Taylor I am afraid Bengali is not there under multi-language setup. Is there any other way?